# Xml to java parsing based on attribute value to a separate variable

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, converters, xstream

I am working on XML to java parsing. I have a scenario similar to this.

I need to parse all **EMPLOYEE** elements with attribute `PERMANENT="Y"` in one member and with attribute `PERMANENT="N"` in another member.

```
<EMPLOYEE PERMANENT="Y">
    <DETAILS NAME="AA"  ID="1"  AGE="28" />
    <DETAILS NAME="BB"  ID="2"  AGE="29" />
</EMPLOYEE>
<EMPLOYEE PERMANENT="N">
   <DETAILS NAME="CC"  ID="3"  AGE="28" />
    <DETAILS NAME="DD"  ID="4"  AGE="29" />
</EMPLOYEE>
```

Java

```
public class Employee
{

   // @XStreamAlias("EMPLOYEE") and attribute PERMANENT="Y"
    private Details permanentEmployee;

   // @XStreamAlias("EMPLOYEE") and attribute PERMANENT="Y"
    private Details tempEmployee;

}
```

I am not sure how to do this.

Can some one help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


public class ParseXML {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse (new File("D:/test.xml"));

        NodeList elt = doc.getElementsByTagName("EMPLOYEE");
        for (int k = 0; k < elt.getLength(); k++) {
            Node firstNode3 = elt.item(k);
            Element elt1 = (Element) firstNode3;
            String att=elt1.getAttribute("PERMANENT");
            System.out.println("\n\nPERMANENT: "+att);

            NodeList nodes = elt1.getElementsByTagName("DETAILS");
            for(int i=0;i<nodes.getLength();i++){
                Node childNode = nodes.item(i);
                Element elt2 = (Element) childNode;
                System.out.println("---"+elt2.getNodeName());
                System.out.println("NAME:"+elt2.getAttribute("NAME"));
                System.out.println("ID:"+elt2.getAttribute("ID"));
                System.out.println("AGE:"+elt2.getAttribute("AGE"));
            }

        }//end of for
    }
```